# Aggregate Design for Ledger

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, accounting

I'm trying to design a double-entry ledger with DDD and running into some trouble with defining aggregate roots. There are three domain models:

1. `LedgerLine`: individual line items that have data such as amount, timestamp they are created at, etc.
2. `LedgerEntry`: entries into the ledger. Each entry contains multiple `LedgerLine`s where the debit and credit lines must balance.
3. `LedgerAccount`: accounts in the ledger. There are two types of accounts: (1) internal accounts (e.g. cash) (2) external accounts (e.g. linked bank accounts). External accounts can be added/removed.

After reading some articles online (e.g. this one: https://lorenzo-dee.blogspot.com/2013/06/domain-driven-design-accounting-domain.html?m=0). It seems like `LedgerEntry` should be one aggregate root, holding references to `LedgerLine`s. `LedgerAccount` should be the other aggregate root. `LedgerLine`s would hold the corresponding `LedgerAccount`'s ID.

While this makes a lot of sense, I'm having trouble figuring out how to update the balance of ledger accounts when ledger lines are added. The above article suggests that the balance should be calculated on the fly, which means it wouldn't need to be updated when `LedgerEntry`s are added. However, I'm using Amazon QLDB for the ledger, and their solutions engineer specifically recommended that the balance should be computed and stored on the `LedgerAccount` since QLDB is not optimized for such kind of "scanning through lots of documents" operation.

Now the dilemma ensues:

1. If I update the `balance` field synchronously when adding `LedgerEntry`s, then I would be updating two aggregates in one operation, which violates the consistency boundary.
2. If I update the `balance` field asynchronously after receiving the event emitted by the "Add `LedgerEntry`" operation, then I could be reading a stale balance on the account if I add another `LedgerEntry` that spends the balance on the account, which could lead to overdrafts.
3. If I subsume the `LedgerAccount` model into the same aggregate of `LedgerEntry`, then I lose the ability to add/remove individual `LedgerAccount` since I can't query them directly.
4. If I get rid of the `balance` field and compute it on the fly, then there could be performance problems given (1) QLDB limitation (2) the fact that the number of ledger lines is unbounded.

So what's the proper design here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Saga Pattern to ensure the whole process completes or fails.

Here's a primer ... https://medium.com/@lfgcampos/saga-pattern-8394e29bbb85

- I'd add 'reserved funds' owned collection to the Ledger Account.
- A Ledger Account will have 'Actual' balance and 'Available Balance'.
- 'Available Balance' is 'Actual' balance less the value of 'reserved funds'

Using a Saga to manage the flow:

1. Try to reserve funds on the Account aggregate.  The Ledger Account will check its available balance (actual minus total of reserved funds) and if sufficient, add another reserved funds to its collection.  If reservation succeeds, the account aggregate will return a reservation unique id.  If reservation fails, then the entry cannot be posted.
2. Try to complete the double entry bookkeeping.  If it fails, send a 'release reservation' command to the Account aggregate quoting the reservation unique id, which will remove the reservation and we're back to where we started.
3. After double entry bookkeeping is complete, send a command to Account to 'complete' reservation with reservation unique id.  The Account aggregate will then remove the reservation and adjust its actual balance.

In this way, you can manage a distributed transaction without the possibility of an account going overdrawn.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I'm understanding correctly, is this one command enqueuing another command?

Comment: Not really.  That would result in some undesirable tight-coupling.  It's more of an additional architectural concept of 'orchestration' where the orchestration has the responsibility of orchestrating a number of lower level commands, each of which can be decoupled from the other commands that take part in the overall orchestration managed by the saga.  A saga could be event driven so the caller initiates the first command and the saga listens and takes over after that first command fires a 'done' event. In your case I'd make the saga the command itself that is called by the client.

Comment: So is this adding a coordination layer on top to run two commands in one go, and we are effectively making the two aggregates strongly consistent? New to this Saga pattern and trying to understand exactly what's going on here. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah.  The fact is that you have two separate aggregates that you want to update.  As discussed, elsewhere, it's bad practice for a single command to update two aggregates, so the Saga sits above and coordinates.  The important this is that the Saga is itself stateful and should persist that state.  That way, in case of system failure part way thru the saga it will know where it was in its orchestration and can continue upon restart.  The saga is responsible for ensuring 'eventual' consistency across multiple aggregates.

Answer (score -1):

An aggregate root should serve as a transaction boundary. A multi-legged transaction spans multiple accounts, hence an account cannot be.

So a ledger itself is an aggregate root. An accounting transaction should correspond to database transaction.

Actually, "ledger itself" doesn't mean a singleton. It can be org branch * time period ledger. And it usually is in non-computer event-sourcing systems.

Update.

A ledger account balances is merely a view into the ledger. And as a view it has a state as of some known event. When making up a decision whether to accept an operation or not, you should make sure that the actual state of the ledger is the latest state processed as of the balances. If it is not - the newer events should be processed first, and then an account operation should be tried again.